# Type Mismatch Error (13) on Split function call

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am working on a project that extracts the URLs of 9 images. If one is not available, it is represented by the "missing-image" URL. I need to cycle through the list and process any that are not "missing". I used the TextJoin function to build the list (some originating columns are non-contiguous), with the pipe ("|") symbol as the delimiter.

```
    Dim VarSKU, MissingImage, Images(), HandleCol As String
    ...
        Images = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "|")
```

I omitted the code between the two statements. None of it makes any reference whatsoever to Images.

I confirmed that the active cell is the one I need to process. Its value is: [http://www.image.src/url_image/0050IG-RN-2160-PH0.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg|http://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg](http://www.image.src/url_image/0050IG-RN-2160-PH0.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg%7Chttp://www.image.src/url_image/missing-image.jpg)

I cannot see why the error is being thrown. I checked the VarTypes of both arguments - they are both String. Images was declared as a String Array.

I must be missing something obvious. Please help.

Comment: `Images` is a `Variant` array, not a `String` array. Your options are either `Images`, `Images As Variant`, or `Images() As String`.

Comment: Btw, `VarSKU` and  `MissingImage` are both `Variant`s. If you want them to be `String`s, you have to repeat the type for each one. `VarSKU As String`, `MissingImage As String`.

Comment: Thank you, @BigBen. I did not realize that providing a list of variables ending with "AS <Type>" would not set all of them to that Type. That is good to know and likely explains the error.